# Prevent focused div from scrolling with arrow keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have a div component with an inner scrollbar and I'd like to prevent the up/down arrow keys from scrolling when the element is focused (mouse click on the element), as they are used for other events (e.g. zoom).

The only solution I found was to attach an event listener to the document, however, it disables all default arrow keys events, such as moving the cursor in an input field.

Here is an example (in React):
https://codesandbox.io/s/rsc-live-example-fze6z

How to reproduce:

- Click with the mouse on the inner div (with the text)
- Click the down arrow key -> div scrolls down

Is there a way to prevent the scroll without disabling it on the document level?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

This missing piece was adding `tab-index='0'` to the component (I updated the code above). Thanks @Jarvan

Comment: Seems your example is working, what is that you were not able to solve ?

Comment: @NarkhedeTushar when you click on the div and then the down arrow key it scrolls the div. I want to prevent that

Answer (score 4):

You can filter the events which you don't want to prevent, such as arrow event in input.

```
if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()!=="input" &&(e.key === "ArrowUp" || e.key === "ArrowDown")) {
          e.preventDefault();
}
```

Then in input the cursor move will not be prevented.

But it won't work if the event you want to keep is some behavior in same element.

E.g. you have some children can be focus in the 'prevent arrow up/down scroll' div, you want to keep the ability to move focus between children by using arrow up/down. In that case I guess you have to implement you customize scrollbar then you have the full control, because in browser behavior I don't see a way to separate the single 'scroll' action.

*Update:*

If you know which component or area you want to effect, just add to that area. Like in your demo code:

```
<div tabindex="0"
      onKeyDown={e => {
        console.log(e);
        if (e.key === "ArrowUp" || e.key === "ArrowDown") {
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log(e.key);
          return false;
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
      }}
    >
      {result}
    </div>
```

Comment: I want to prevent a single component from scrolling without affecting the rest of the components (i.e. allow using the keyboard arrows). I can't find a way to capture the arrow key event anywhere except for the document or the body.

Comment: Then why don't you just add event to the single component? I remove your document level event and move it to div level and it works fine.

Comment: I tried adding the event listener to the component but it doesn't work. The event is not firing at all

Comment: I was missing the tabIndex. What a waste of time :( Thanks!!!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Adding `e.preventDefault()` to `onKeyDown` solved the issue. You're awesome!